# How to use Primefaces Dialog with @ViewScoped setting Parameters?

Tags: jsf, parameters, dialog

I'm facing again problem with Dialog.

What I intend to do is a common dialog that will be used for the whole appication, It has its own managed bean that is inherited by other MBs that need to use it, then some parameters are set by example super.setParam(...) to set some data to be displayed.The problem is that when the dialog is being loaded a getter method is called to retrieve the parameters set and it is no longer there, its just null.

I believe that due to the MB being @ViewScoped the container is creating a new instance when the dialog is beying loaded, but the setter method was called before it, so the new instance return to the default values. Using a @SessionScoped would solve the problem but it is not a good choice.

As a work around I tried to set the parameter in the request and then read it in the getter method but it is no longer there either.

Is there some way to get it working?

```
//here I put the parameter
    public void setParam(MyObject myObject) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put("params", myObject);

    public MyObject getMyObject() {
// now the parameter is no longer there...
            Object objet = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("params");
.... after doing some things
        return anotherObject;
    }

    }
```

> > > > > EDIT<<<<

All starts with this button on a "client.xhtml"

```
    <p:commandButton value="Call Dialog" ajax="true"
                actionListener="#{subDialogMB.startProcess}"
                 >
                 </p:commandButton>

@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean
@javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped
public class SubDialogMB extends SuperDialogMBean() {

    public void starProcess() {
        try {
            MyObject myObject = service.CreateMyObject....
            super.setMyObject();
            super.shpwDialog();

        }

}

@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean
public class SuperDialogMBean() {

    public void setMyObject(MyObject myObject) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put("params", myObject);
    }

public MyObject getMyObject(){

        public MyObject getMyObject() {
    // now the parameter is no longer there...
                Object objet = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("params");
    .... after doing some things
            return anotherObject;
        }
}

public void showDialog() {

    Map<String,Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    options.put("modal", true);
    options.put("draggable", false);
    options.put("resizable", false);
    options.put("contentHeight", 900);
    options.put("contentWidth", 1100);
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("myDialog", options, null);
}


}
```

and finally in the Dialog xhtml

```
<p:outputText value="#{superDialogMBean.someValue}" />
```

Comment: You have a CDI design problem. Can you show the sequence that your MBs are being called/instantiated plus the xhtml?

Comment: Ok done, thx for your attention.

Comment: It is not clear where is the dialog xhtml snippet. If it isn't within the startProcess caller view ViewScoped can't be used by definition.

Comment: The dialog.xhtml is called in the chain -> SubDialogMB.startProcess() -> SuperDialogMBean.showDialog() -> RequestContext.openDialog(). I tried an class variable to hold myObject value instead of putting in the request but without success.